# Copy a file from remote to local

Tags: ssh, scp

I am trying to copy a file from 10.10.10.99:/home/shantanu/ to the localhost.
The only problem is that I need to tunnel the connection through 10.10.10.98
Something like this does not work....

```
ssh shantanu@10.10.10.98 "ssh shantanu@10.10.10.99 cp /home/shantanu/test.txt . "
```

The thread "ssh tunnel via multiple hops" is too confusing.

https://superuser.com/questions/96489/ssh-tunnel-via-multiple-hops

Comment: That's because the accepted solution is not a very good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use "cp" for copying files between SSH-enabled hosts, use scp. Something like this should suffice for your needs right now:

```
ssh -f shantanu@10.10.10.98 -L 41111:10.10.10.99:22 -N
scp -P 41111 shantanu@localhost:/home/shantanu/test.txt .
```

It should be noted that the first command creates a tunnel (accessible only from your localhost, but still) that you might want to close after transferring the files. Or leave it open, it's not a huge security risk since you still have to auth against the second host to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Just pipe the local file through a chain of SSH pipes to its final destination:

```
ssh shantanu@10.10.10.98 "ssh shantanu@10.10.10.99 'cat >test.txt'" </home/shantanu/test.txt
```

The only tricky part can be the double quoting required to get the shell redirection executed on the target machine.

Answer (score 0):

(Not directly related to this but..) you can also create a Reverse SSH Tunnel.

on Remote server:

```
ssh -fN -R 7000:localhost:22 username@yourMachine-ipaddress
```

Now do an ssh connection request from your machine to your own machine at port 7000:

```
ssh username@localhost -p 7000
```